# remove commas from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, list

(bad english sry)
i tried to create a to do list website, but everytime i try to add a new item the commas of the array appears, i`ve tried everything in my knowledge...
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <h1 id="todo">Suas tarefas: </h1>
    <input type="text" name="" id="inserirtarefa">
    <button onclick="adicionarbutton()">
        adicionar
    </button>
    <button onclick="removerbutton()">
        Remover
    </button>    
    <ol id="lista">
        
    </ol>



</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
let lista = []

function adicionarbutton(){
    //pega a tarefa e adiciona
    let novaTarefa = document.getElementById(`inserirtarefa`).value
    lista.push(`<li>${novaTarefa} </li>`)
    //escreve a lista na tela
    document.getElementById("lista").innerHTML = lista

    //limpa a caixa de input
    document.getElementById(`inserirtarefa`).value = " "
}

function removerbutton(){
    let removerTarefa = prompt(`Qual tarefa deseja remover?`)
    lista.splice((removerTarefa-1), 1)           
    document.getElementById("lista").innerHTML = lista
}
```

The site is in portuguese

i`ve tried to use join and nothing happens...
the only problem to me is just the commas between

Comment: Don't use `).innerHTML = lista` rather use `createElement` to make a new item then append that to the parent.

Comment: You are displaying the array in the html element. The HTML page will automatically convert the array to a string when it displays it, but the commas are included. If you type console.log(lista.toString()) you will see the same thing. So you should use join. innerHtml=lista.join(""); should work fine. What do you mean nothing happens?

Comment: *i`ve tried to use join*: please share that attempt. Did you specify a delimiter?